# Laravel - Prevent multiple requests at the same time creating duplicate records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, deadlock

I have a cancel order method that refunds the user.

However, using the API, if a user calls the endpoint twice (in a loop) for the same record, it refunds the user twice. If I try 3x Api calls at once, first 2 requests gets the refund, 3rd request doesn't.

```
public function cancelOrder($orderId) {
   // First I tried to solve with cache, 
   // but it is not fast enough to catch the loop
   if (Cache::has("api-canceling-$orderId")) {
        return response()->json(['message' => "Already cancelling"], 403);
   }

   Cache::put("api-voiding-$labelId", true, 60);

   // Here I get the transaction, and check if 'transaction->is_cancelled'.
   // I thought cache will be faster but apparently not enough.
   $transaction = Transaction::where('order_id', $orderId)
         ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
         ->where('type', "Order Charge")
         ->firstOrFail();

   if ($transaction->is_cancelled) {
        return response()->json(['message' => "Order already cancelled"], 403);
   }

   // Here I do the api call to 3rd party service and wait for response
   try {
       $result = (new OrderCanceller)->cancel($orderId);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 403);
   }

   $transaction->is_cancelled = true;
   $transaction->save();

   // This is the operation getting called twice.
   Transaction::createCancelRefund($transaction);

   return response()->json(['message' => 'Refund is made to your account']);
}
```

The `createCancelRefund()` method looks like this:

```
public static function createCancelRefund($transaction) {
     Transaction::create([
         'user_id' => $transaction->user_id,
         'credit_movement' => $transaction->credit_movement * -1,
         'type' => "Order Refund"
     ]);
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Wrapping everything inside `cancelOrder()` method into `DB::transaction({}, 5)` closure. (Also tried `DB::beginTransaction()` approach)
- Using `->lockForUpdate()` on `$transaction = Transaction::where('order_id', $orderId)`... query.
- Wrapping `createCancelRefund()` content inside `DB::transaction({}, 5)`, but I think as it's `create()` it didn't help.
- Tried using cache but it was not as fast.
- Looked up to throttling but doesn't seem like it can prevent this (if I say 2 request/min, duplicate creation still occurs)

What is the proper way of preventing duplicate refund creations inside `createCancelRefund()`?

Comment: you have to have some global (ie DB) entry which stores the status of the refund. So if refund is already refunded do nothing on second request

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Atomic Lock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#managing-locks) solved my problem.

> *Atomic locks allow for the manipulation of distributed locks without worrying about race conditions. For example, Laravel Forge uses atomic locks to ensure that only one remote task is being executed on a server at a time*

```
public function cancelOrder($orderId) {
   return Cache::lock("api-canceling-{$orderId}")->get(function () use ($orderId) {
      $transaction = Transaction::where('order_id', $orderId)
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('type', "Order Charge")
            ->firstOrFail();

      if ($transaction->is_cancelled) {
           return response()->json(['message' => "Order already cancelled"], 403);
      }

      try {
         $result = (new OrderCanceller)->cancel($orderId);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
       return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 403);
      }

      $transaction->is_cancelled = true;
      $transaction->save();

      // This is the operation getting called twice.
      Transaction::createCancelRefund($transaction);

      return response()->json(['message' => 'Refund is made to your account']);
   });
   
   return response()->json(['message' => "Already cancelling"], 403);
}
```

Comment: you did not return from the statement `Cache::lock("api-canceling-{$orderId}")->get(function () use ($orderId) {` Are you sure your code is returning a response in case of success

Comment: @hhsadiq you made me realise that if I have a bug inside the lock closure and it crashes, it stays locked forever. Do you have any strategy to handle this better?

Comment: so we its been explained really good, and it handles the situation to avoid forever lock. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430799/why-does-cachelock-return-false-in-laravel-7 

We have implemented his recommended approach, and it will be going live today. Let's see how it works on production :-)