# Laravel Transaction Not Working as Expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, concurrency, laravel-8

I have a code snippet that updates the user's last active time on the website. The steps involved are

```
1. Get User Id from Auth
2. Check if this user's status = online entry exists in the logs.
3. If the entry exist then update the last active time.
4. If the entry doesn't exist then insert in the logs with following Fields UserId, Start Time, Status, Last Active Time and bunch of more fields which is irrelevant to this question.
```

There is a unique key constraint on userId and Start Time. Initially, it was not there to make the inserts faster but due to concurrency(2)/duplicate requests, I had to do that.

Now making it unique makes it obvious that there will not be duplicate entries at the DB level, but that doesn't stop the application to attempt it.

To stop even attempting the application,  added the Transaction Code.

```
DB::beginTransaction()
Steps 1-4
DB::commit()
```

I thought this would solve all the problems. But all in vain. Can anyone help where I am going wrong?

```
 DB::beginTransaction();
            if(!Log::checkIfUserOnline($userId)){
                Log::create([
                    'user_id'=>$userId,
                    'start_time'=>Carbon::now(),
                    'status'=>'online',
                    'last_active_time'=>Carbon::now()
                ]);
            }else{
                Log::where(['user_id'=>$userId,'status'=>'online'])->update([
                    'last_active_time'=>Carbon::now(),

                ]);
            }
            DB::commit(); 


public static function checkIfUserOnline($userId)
{
    return self::where(['user_id'=>$userId, 'status'=>'online'])->count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: `To stop even attempting the application, added the Transaction Code`. Transactions are not meant for that. You might want to take a look at [updateOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)

Comment: @Jigar agreed on that part, but again how do I solve this? I was just hoping that it would solve and what made me think so i don't even know :(

Comment: Transactions are not locks. One transaction won't be blocked until another one completes meaning you might have multiple ones running concurrently trying to save the same data (only one will succeed in your case). On the other hand laravel does have [locks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#atomic-locks)

Answer (score 0):

```
Log::updateOrCreate([
    'user_id' => $userId,
], [
    'last_active_time' => Carbon::now(),
    'status' => 'online',
]);
```

Remove the transaction piece.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but the problem is I am looking for a solution to a bigger problem where there are multiple checks possibly across different tables. How would then I solve this? The above problem statement is one part. Though i will try adding this block in a small section. But what if there are multiple tables involved.

Comment: `But what if there are multiple tables involved` you will have to elaborate in OP.

Comment: additional problem in this is start_time how do I only assign value in case of creating? I don't want to touch field in case of an update. DB default value is not an option here

Comment: Just hypothetically assume there are Log1 and Log2 two tables, I look up using Log1 and Insert into Log2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430799/why-does-cachelock-return-false-in-laravel-7

I think this is actual that would work for my case.